# How do I remove the "Save draft" button from every page of a multi-step form?

Tags: webforms

I have a multi-step webform and I want to add a save draft button however it needs to be added only to the last preview page and not all step pages.

I have used settings within submission to activate saving draft however the button appears on each page. Any way to hide, without changing code but just through configuration/settings?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new module and then you can check the `$form_state` page to conditionally enable to disable buttons.

```
function submission_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_submission_xyz') {
    $form['actions']['button or field']['#access'] = $form_state->get('current_page' )== 'abcd';
}
```

Comment: Wasn't there a simple setting/permission you can uncheck?

Comment: There is no setting/permission; this is a good solution. Another approach would be using CSS to hide the 'Save draft' button, which is not as good a solution.